Console Navigation doesn't allow for app menu interaction
I'm just starting to write some UTAM tests and it's great, but i've hit a roadblock. When the tests start from an app that uses standard app navigation (root page object navex/desktopLayoutContainer), i can change apps at will, but when it starts from an app that uses console navigation (root page object navex/workspaceManager) this is not possible, even though the button is present. Anyone using UTAM with console navigation managed to work around this issue?
Below is the helper method i'm developing to make that happen
import DesktopLayoutContainer from "salesforce-pageobjects/navex/pageObjects/desktopLayoutContainer";
import AppLauncherMenu from "salesforce-pageobjects/global/pageObjects/appLauncherMenu";
import AppLauncherModal from "salesforce-pageobjects/global/pageObjects/appLauncherModal";
import HoverableLink from "salesforce-pageobjects/records/pageObjects/hoverableLink";

export async function navigateToApp(appName) {
    const container = await utam.load(DesktopLayoutContainer);
    const appNav = await container.getAppNav();
    const appLauncherHeader = await appNav.getAppLauncherHeader();
    const appLauncherButton = await appLauncherHeader.getButton();
    await appLauncherButton.click();

    const appLauncherMenu = await utam.load(AppLauncherMenu);
    const viewAllButton = await appLauncherMenu.getLwcButton();
    await viewAllButton.click();

    const appLauncherModal = await utam.load(AppLauncherModal);
    const accordion = await appLauncherModal.getAccordion();
    const allItemsSection = await accordion.getAccordionSectionByTitle("All Items");
    const links = await allItemsSection.getSectionContents(HoverableLink);
    
    links.forEach(link => async () => {
        const linkText = await link.getLinkText();
        if(linkText === appName)
        {
            await link.clickLink();
        }
    })
}


I just gave it a try and I confirm that it's not possible with the latest base page objects (v7.0.1 as of now).
Using the UTAM Chrome browser extension, I can drill down to the console nav but there's no method on the page object for selecting the App Launcher.

I will share this feedback with the UTAM team.

Thank you so much!
